# KeyStoreException: getting null key

Tags: java

I have created mdm.pem,intermediate.pem , root.pem using the [reference](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning).

As a vendor action

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in mdm_identity.cer -out mdm.pem

openssl x509 -inform der -in AppleWWDRCA.cer -out intermediate.pem

openssl x509 -inform der -in AppleIncRootCertificate.cer -out root.pem
```

As a customer,
created a CSR using openssl :

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out customerPrivateKey.pem 2048


openssl req -new -key customerPrivateKey.pem -out customer.csr
```

then convert customer.csr to der format :

```
openssl req -inform pem -outform der -in customer.csr -out customer.der
```

After that using the java sample code downloaded from the same [reference](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning) ,I was trying to create plist.xml and plist_encoded. But I am getting the null key exception.

```
    private PrivateKey extractPrivateKey(String path2keystore) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException
        {
            String alias = "test";//Change to your alias
            String password = "test";//Change to your password

            KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            caKs.load(new FileInputStream(new File(path2keystore)), password.toCharArray());

   //----------issue in the below line

   Key key = caKs.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());

   //getting null key in the above line for "key" object


            return (PrivateKey)key;
        }
```

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong. If someone else also faced similar type of problem please help me.

I am attaching full Test.java source code below:

```
package com.softhinker;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.Element;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
/**
 * This class is to generate encoded plist for iOS MDM signing request.
 * Below files should be in the folder : 
 *  - customer.der
 *  - intermediate.pem
 *  - mdm.pem
 *  - root.pem
 *  - vendor.p12
 * 
 * Then upload 'plist_encoded' to https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/ to 
 * generate the certificate for your customer.
 * 
 * [Author Introduction]
 * Softhinker.com is a Singapore-based independent software vendor, 
 * focusing on J2EE, Android, iOS, Google Apps development and consultancy.
 * Please visit us at http://www.softhinker.com for more details.
 * 
 * @author Softhinker
 *
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL dirUrl = Test.class.getResource(".");
        URL keyUrl = new URL(dirUrl, "vendor.p12");
        String keyPath = keyUrl.getPath().replaceAll("%20", " ");
        System.out.println(keyPath);

        BASE64Encoder b64en = new BASE64Encoder();

        Test test = new Test();
        PrivateKey privateKey = test.extractPrivateKey(keyPath);

        URL csrUrl = new URL(dirUrl, "customer.der");
        String csrPath = csrUrl.getPath().replace("%20", " ");
        byte[] csrBytes = test.readCSR(csrPath);
        String csr = b64en.encode(csrBytes);

        byte[] sigBytes = test.signCSR(privateKey, csrBytes);
        String signature = b64en.encode(sigBytes);

        URL mdmUrl = new URL(dirUrl, "mdm.pem");
        String mdmPath = mdmUrl.getPath().replace("%20", " ");
        String mdm = test.readCertChain(mdmPath);

        URL intermediateUrl = new URL(dirUrl, "intermediate.pem");
        String intermediatePath = intermediateUrl.getPath().replace("%20", " ");
        String intermediate = test.readCertChain(intermediatePath);

        URL rootUrl = new URL(dirUrl, "root.pem");
        String rootPath = rootUrl.getPath().replace("%20", " ");
        String root = test.readCertChain(rootPath);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(mdm);
        sb.append(intermediate);
        sb.append(root);

        test.generatePlist(csr, sb.toString(), signature);
    }

    private byte[] signCSR(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] csr) throws Exception {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA");
        sig.initSign(privateKey);
        sig.update(csr);
        byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();
        return signatureBytes;
    }

    private PrivateKey extractPrivateKey(String path2keystore) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException
    {
        String alias = "test";//Change to your alias
        String password = "test";//Change to your password

        KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        caKs.load(new FileInputStream(new File(path2keystore)), password.toCharArray());
        Key key = caKs.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
        return (PrivateKey)key;
    }

    private byte[] readCSR(String path2csr) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path2csr);
        byte[] csrBytes = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(csrBytes);
        fis.close();
        return csrBytes;
    }

    private String readCertChain(String path2certchain) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path2certchain);
        byte[] csrBytes = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(csrBytes);
        fis.close();
        return new String(csrBytes);
    }

    private void generatePlist(String csr, String chain, String signature) throws IOException
    {
        Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
        document.addDocType("plist", "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN", "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd");

        Element plist = document.addElement("plist");
        plist.addAttribute("version", "1.0");

        Element dict = plist.addElement("dict");

        Element csrKey = dict.addElement("key");
        csrKey.addText("PushCertRequestCSR");
        Element csrStr = dict.addElement("string");
        csrStr.addText(csr);

        Element chainKey = dict.addElement("key");
        chainKey.addText("PushCertCertificateChain");
        Element chainStr = dict.addElement("string");
        chainStr.addText(chain);

        Element sigKey = dict.addElement("key");
        sigKey.addText("PushCertSignature");
        Element sigStr = dict.addElement("string");
        sigStr.addText(signature);

        String plistxml = document.asXML();
        BASE64Encoder b64en = new BASE64Encoder();
        String encodedplist = b64en.encode(plistxml.getBytes());

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("plist.xml");
        document.write(writer);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("plist_encoded");
        out.write(encodedplist);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("File is generated.");
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the keystore contains a key with the alias "test"?

Comment: I am sure about the password which is "test",but about alias I have no idea, so I have given same for alias also "test", as it was already in the sample code.

Comment: Ok, in a console use keystore to list the aliases in the vendor.p12 file: keytool -list -keystore vendor.p12 -keystoreType PKCS12. If you're not using the correct alias, then this is the cause of your NPE

Comment: Thanks Chris.My problem is solved now.I was giving wrong alias.

Comment: No problem - please mark this question as closed

Comment: The alias I get from the command is >>    le-617d6dd8-fe5a-488a-939c-a2ada5327c20   <<   But when I enter this in the Java script, I get the same error ie. "Key must not be null". Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am able to solve the problem.Problem was wrong alias.I listed out the aliases for the vendor.p12 and I got the correct alias,which I passed in   `Key key = caKs.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());`
I solved the problem as per Chris' comment above.

Comment: The alias I get from the command is >>    le-617d6dd8-fe5a-488a-939c-a2ada5327c20   <<   But when I enter this in the Java script, I get the same error ie. "Key must not be null". Any clue?